# Android print via bluetooth

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth

I'm develop an app for manage invoices, and I have the necessity to print the invoice via bluetooth.
There are API for bluetooth printing?? Or there is a way to do this?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

There are bluetooth printer available in market. I found Zebra the best. These printer support both Android/iOS, and you can get the SDK for the printer from their website.

As far as Zebra printer is concerned, i found its SDK to be well documented and easy to use.

Also in Zebra printer Android SDK, i found some example that were very helpful to me for understanding the functionality.